# difference between similar bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

in refereing to bit-wise operators, what is the difference between ! and ~ ? I feel like they both flip the bits, but 1 maybe adds a 1 to the final answer?

```
~0xC4

compared to

!0xC4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`!` is not a bitwise operator, it's a boolean operator.

The boolean operators operate on truth values, which are generally `int`. Any non-zero value is true, while 0 is false. The result is always `1` for true, `0` for false.

- `!` is boolean not
- `&&` is boolean and
- `||` is boolean or

These are the ones used in e.g. `if` since it needs a boolean value. The boolean and/or operators are also short-circuiting, which means they stop evaluating when the result is known. This is good, it means `1 || crash_and_burn()` will never crash and burn.

But the bitwise operators operate on each bit of the integer-typed argument(s), after promotions and such of course.

- `~` is bitwise not
- `&` is bitwise and
- `|` is bitwise or
- `^` is bitwise exlusive-or (xor)

The bitwise operators are (of course) not short-circuiting, that wouldn't make any sense since they just operate on pairs of bits. Note that while there is a `^` bitwise operator, there is no `^^` boolean xor operator.

Answer (score 2):

~0xC4 flips bits and does this:

```
1100 0100 (0xC4) --> 0011 1011 (0x3B)
```

!0xC4 flips logical truth value and does this:

```
True (0xC4) --> False (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`!` and `~` are two different types of operators. `!` is the **logical negation** and `~` is the **bitwise negation**.

**Logical operators** are those which use mathematical logic.

For example: `Sally went to the market and bought milk.`

If `p: Sally went to the market.`

And `q: Sally bought milk.`

Then the statement can be shown as `p && q`.

Now, **Bitwise operators** are those that play with the binary representation of each number.

If `p = 10` this can be expressed as `p = 1010 (binary)`.

And `q = 12` this can be expressed as `q = 1100 (binary)`.

Then `p & q = 1000 (binary)`.

Same for `!` and `~` .

`!p = Sally did not go to the market.`

`~p = 0101`.

In C (and C++) there is **no separation** between booleans (True False ideas) and int. Which means that booleans are represented by integers as `True = 1` and `False = 0`.

Here `0xC4 = 1100 0100`

So, `!0xC4 = 0000 0000 and ~0xC4 = 0011 1011 [0x3B]`.

***Tip:*** If you wish to convert a certain variable to boolean (ie `x = 5 -> x = 1`) then use `!!x`.

`!!x -> !(!(5)) -> !(0) -> 1`