# 2 conditions for if statements joined together, difference between && and &

Tags: c, if-statement

How do I join 2 conditions in my if statement? Example `if(int i=1 AND int x=0)`? Whats the difference between  using && and &?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between & and && in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617159/difference-between-and-in-c)

Comment: What does your *text book* say?

Comment: Use `&&`.  The `&` operator is for bitwise operations.